# Where can I configure "erase mac"

Tags: mac, icloud

iCloud offers the service to remotely wipe (erase) a mac, as you can remotely erase an iPhone.
Where can I change this setting, e.g. disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Find My Mac* feature can be enabled and disabled in the iCloud settings (System Preferences → iCloud)

[image]

You cannot disable just the "erase" feature: the locate, lock and erase features must be managed as a single option.